# Laravel form select currently selected with distinct

Tags: forms, laravel, select, model, eloquent

I'm using distinct and lists to retrieve a list of values that already have been inserted.

```
$listColor = $group->where('map_polygon_color', '!=', '')->distinct('map_polygon_color')->lists('map_polygon_color');
```

generates me a solid list of colors.

Now I fetch (if there is a selected color) the color:

```
$selectedColor = array_search($group->map_polygon_color, $listColor);
```

Ok, I got a list with colors and a currently selected list. Now I send this to a model-binded form:

```
{!! Form::select('map_polygon_color', $listColor, $selectedColor, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Now the question: is there a (simpel) way to do this directly in the template? My selectedColor needs the color list array to retrieve the selected key.

// Edit color array:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => "rgb(75, 0, 130)"
  1 => "rgb(50, 205, 50)"
  2 => "rgb(30, 144, 255)"
  3 => "rgb(255, 140, 0)"
  4 => "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works but you could just make the `$listColor` array like this:

```
[
    'rgb(75, 0, 130)' => 'rgb(75, 0, 130)',
    'rgb(50, 205, 50)' => 'rgb(50, 205, 50)'
    // etc
]
```

By using `map_polygon_color` twice in `lists`:

```
$listColor = $group->where('map_polygon_color', '!=', '')
                   ->distinct('map_polygon_color')
                   ->lists('map_polygon_color', 'map_polygon_color');
```

Then you'd at least not have to do `array_search` and if I understand your structure correctly the model binding should take care of setting the right value:

```
{!! Form::select('map_polygon_color', $listColor, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```